# Facing issues in compilation of idl files using tao_idl in rhel7 machine

Tags: compilation, corba, idl, tao

i am facing issues in compilation of idl file. i have tried with different options with -Cw, -GI and -o all are giving the below errors

tao_idl: "El_file.idl", line 201: error in lookup of symbols File::File1_operationFailed

tao_idl: "El_file.idl", line 204: error in lookup of symbols File::File1_operationFailed

tao_idl: "El_file.idl", line 208: error in lookup of symbols File::File1_operationFailed

tao_idl: El_file.idl: found 744 errors
Fatal Error - Aborting

Thanks for response john.
line 9 : statement cannot be parsed

line 201: error in lookup of symbol: ptype

line 9 :module Mgr{
          interface intf1;

```
      interface intf2;

      interface intf3;

      ....
      ..
      ...
      ...
      ..
   }
```

enum ptype{
Profile1,
Profile2,
...
...
}

line 201 :struct pstruct{

```
                ptype P1;

             }
```

Comment: Sounds you have an IDL file with illegal IDL in it but without giving us the content of the file we can't help you.

Comment: please check above i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

Your IDL is not legal, you should close the module, enum, and struct with }; and not just }

Comment: sorry john both the struct and enum are closed with };. mistake in copying the code.

Comment: Please update your question with the *exact* IDL that fails, when I added the missing semi-colons on my system it did compile without problems